# How can I put the next row on the bottom of first row using PHP and jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to put the next row on the bottom of my first row. How can I do it? I make table using PHP and jQuery. The problem is when I create more than 1 row the result is in the same line. Can somebody help me regarding to my problem? The data is from my database table.

[image]

```
//PHPCODE.PHP
else if(isset($_POST['btnView'])){
        $selectData = $conn->query("SELECT * from tbl_wedding");
        echo "<table align='center' border='1'>
                <th>Groom FirstName</th>
                <th>Groom MiddleName</th>
                <th>Groom LastName</th>
                <th>Groom DateOfBirth</th>
                <th>Groom Address</th>
                <th>Bride FirstName</th>
                <th>Bride MiddleName</th>
                <th>Bride LastName</th>
                <th>Bride DateOfBirth</th>
                <th>Bride Address</th>
                <th>Reservation Date</th>
                <th>Select Time</th>
                <tr>";

        while($row = $selectData->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "<td>" . $row['GroomFirstName'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['GroomMiddleName'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['GroomLastName'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['GroomDOB'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['GroomAddress'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['BrideFirstName'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['BrideMiddleName'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['BrideLastName'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['BrideDOB'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['BrideAddress'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['ReservationDate'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['SelectTime'] . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr></table>";
    }

//JSCODE.JS
while($row = $selectData->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['MiddleName'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td> " . "<td>" . $row['DateOfBirth'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['Address'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['NameOfFather'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['NameOfMother'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['ReservationDate'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['BapSelectTime'] . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr></table>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enclose the `<th>` and `<td>` by the `<tr>`. `<tr>` indicates row. So each data must be inclined within a row. Isn't it?

```
else if(isset($_POST['btnView'])){
        $selectData = $conn->query("SELECT * from tbl_wedding");
        echo "<table align='center' border='1'>
                <tr>
                <th>Groom FirstName</th>
                <th>Groom MiddleName</th>
                <th>Groom LastName</th>
                <th>Groom DateOfBirth</th>
                <th>Groom Address</th>
                <th>Bride FirstName</th>
                <th>Bride MiddleName</th>
                <th>Bride LastName</th>
                <th>Bride DateOfBirth</th>
                <th>Bride Address</th>
                <th>Reservation Date</th>
                <th>Select Time</th>
                </tr>";

        while($row = $selectData->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row['GroomFirstName'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['GroomMiddleName'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['GroomLastName'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['GroomDOB'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['GroomAddress'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['BrideFirstName'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['BrideMiddleName'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['BrideLastName'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['BrideDOB'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['BrideAddress'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['ReservationDate'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['SelectTime'] . "</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }

//JSCODE.JS
while($row = $selectData->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['MiddleName'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td> " . "<td>" . $row['DateOfBirth'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['Address'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['NameOfFather'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['NameOfMother'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['ReservationDate'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['BapSelectTime'] . "</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
```